# Why you can manipulate object properties without referencing 'this'

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to understand why the following works:

Given that we have

```
var _queries = [];

function Query(queries) {
  _queries = this.queries = queries;
}

Query.prototype.add = function add(query) {
  _queries.push(query);
};
```

Where `add` manipulates `_queries`, instead of `this.queries`.

When we create a new Query object,

```
var query = new Query(['foo']);
query;
//=> Query { queries: ['foo'], add: function... }
query.add('bar');
query;
//=> Query { queries: ['foo', 'bar'], add: function... }
```

It is as if `add` added `bar` to `this.queries`, even though `_queries` was manipulated. It is not intuitive to me why this works.

Comment: Because you've used a global variable. Which is a very bad idea, and will not work with multiple instances.

Comment: This is scoped in a larger function I decided not to include on SO

Answer (score 1):

That's because javascript treats arrays as a reference.

This line of code

```
 _queries = this.queries = queries;
```

will make it so that `_queries` and `this.queries` are pointers to the same in-memory array.

If you changed it to this:

```
 _queries = queries.slice();
 this.queries = queries.slice();
```

Then they would each point to different copies of the array.

(`slice` is the javascript method to clone an array)